Unions UB and endianness
I have a few questions regarding unions and what is safe. Please check my understanding. Given a union like:
union
{
    uint16_t ab;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t a;
    };
};


In C99 and onwards, for example, it is ok to set ab and then read b or a. And then if I modified b, reading ab later on would also be fine.

But in C++, the above is UB.

Whether a or b is the most significant byte (MSB) depends on the endianness of the machine. For example, here a is the MSB for me as it is the second struct field and my machine is little-endian. Therefore, we can't really use unions without caring about endianness.


Is my understanding correct?

"But in CPP, the above is UB.": In ISO C++ the union definition would be ill-formed, not UB, because anonymous structure members do not exist in C++. In practice C++ compilers support the anonymous structure as a language extension in non-strict modes and also support the type punning as an extension for compatibility with C, at least if the types are trivial and standard-layout.

Ah okay, I see. Yes I should have also noted that, I believe that anonymous unions are a C11 feature. Thanks.

"Therefore, we can't really use unions without caring about endianness.": Type punning is not the only use case for a union. The usage pattern that would also be valid in ISO C++ as well as C does not rely on any representation details such as endianess. That's specific only to the type punning pattern.

You should also tag this C++.

@You'reNotARobot "In C99 and onwards, for example, it is ok to set ab and then read b or a. And then if I modified b, reading ab later on would also be fine." --> Yes. (unless on insane compiler that pads the struct.)


Is my understanding correct?

In reality most (if not all) systems will do as you describe for the example code provided. However, it's not guaranteed by the C standard.
As mentioned by user "chux - Reinstate Monica" in a comment, a compliant C compiler is allowed to add padding after every struct member. In such cases, struct member a doesn't share any memory with union member ab so when setting ab, the byte corresponding to a takes unspecified value. You'll probably not find a compiler doing that but the C standard allows it.
For your specific example an array like uint8_t x[2]; would be better than a struct as it solves the padding problem.
While it is legal in C to write to one union member and then read another union member there are in the general case several things that makes it pretty useless.
The question already mentions the endianess problem but there are more to it.
Example:
union
{
    uint16_t ab;
    uint8_t b;
} u;

u.ab = 0x0102;
u.b = 0x03;

After this it's tempting to assume that u.ab now holds either 0x0302 or 0x0103 (depending on endianess) but that's not specified by the standard.
Section 6.2.6.1 (draft n1570) says:

When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

So the C standard allows that the result of u.ab in the above code is either 0x03?? or 0x??03 (depending on endianess). Again, you'll probably not find a compiler/system doing that but the C standard allows it.
In C unsigned integer types can't have trap representations but if your union uses types that has trap representations (on some specific system) then writing one union member may cause another union member to be a trap representation and reading it could be pretty bad.
Another example is struct types that actually have padding. The value of padding bytes can't really be controlled. Basic operations on the struct member may (behind your back) change the padding. If another union member actually uses the same bytes, things get out of control.
There may be simple examples where it's safe to write one union member and then read another. But in the general case there are several problems and it's best to avoid it. At least if you want protable code.
